# Sitecore website not re-directing to login

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When I access my sitecore website, it seems to be authenticating some user -- i can tell because I check the cookies on my browser and see that a session id has been issued. I'm confused as to what user is being auto-authenticated and how i can disable that. I would expect to be required to authenticate via the login page that I've specified in the sites section of the sitecore web.config, but I'm not getting re-directed to the login page. Is there some anonymous access granted to a default user that I need to disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `extranet\anonymous` user is used. If you do not want anonymous access you should break the inheritance for that user, probably on your home item.

Do make sure that your login page is accessible for that user though, otherwise nobody can login..

Comment: Thanks! Although in my case, i was using a custom domain, i noticed that the anonymous user for that domain had read permissions on all items. I had to disable access for this user by using the "require login" preset.